# Formula for critical values of Wilcoxin and U-Test? (in R)

Tags: r, statistics

In R: How do I write a loop that generates a table with the critical values for a Wilcoxon test for dependent samples and a U test for independent samples? I can't find a clear mathematical formula for it. For example, for a Wilcoxon test, the critical value for an n of 8 and a one-tailed alpha of 0.05 is 5. The critical value for an n of 0 and a one-tailed alpha of 0.05 is 8. Thank you for your help.

[Wilxocin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7iS7.png)
[U-Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU5nL.png)

I couldn't find any clear mathematical formulas. My prof suggested that these numbers just come from a certain textbook. He suggested combinatorical analysis.

Comment: `qsignrank` and `qwilcox` will be helpful. You won't need a loop as you can supply vectors for sample size as well as probability, e. g.: `qsignrank(n = 1:16, p = c(.001, .01, .05))`